# PHP JSON Include

Tags: php, json

I want to write a PHP script that will run as a cron job on my server. I need it to download JSON from a URL and process it. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Can anybody help or point me to a good resource?

Comment: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are using php 5.2
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Otherwise json.org lists a ton of php json parsers